# Error in React Component - Failed to validate the users registration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the User Registration Code when i try to register a new user. even after entering the same password. I keep getting the "Passwords do not match" error message. I fail to understand where I am going wrong.

I request you to help understand where I am going wrong. Thanks for your help.

I have been trying to fix this for the last couple of days. however I have not been able to find a solution.

This is the code for the User Registration Component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
// react-bootstrap components
import { Button, Card, Container, Row, Col, Form, FloatingLabel, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";

require("dotenv").config();

const api = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST}/api/register`;
function UserRegistration() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    passwordConfirmation: "",
  });
  const [isSubmittedSignup, setIsSubmittedSignup] = useState(false);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [fadeProp, setFadeProp] = useState({ fade: "" });
  const [successAlert, setSuccessAlert] = useState("show-success");
  const [errorAlert, setErrorAlert] = useState("show-error");

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setInterval(() => {
      if (fadeProp.fade === "fade-in") {
        setFadeProp({ fade: "fade-out" });
      }
      if (successAlert === "show-success") {
        setSuccessAlert("hide-success");
      }
      if (errorAlert === "show-error") {
        setErrorAlert("hide-error");
      }
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(timeout);
  }, [fadeProp, successAlert, errorAlert]);

  const handleChangeEmail = (event) => {
    setUser({
      ...user,
      email: event.target.value,
    });
    if (user.email) {
      errors.email = "";
      setErrors(errors);
    }
  };

  const handleChangePassword = (event) => {
    setUser({
      ...user,
      password: event.target.value,
    });
    if (user.password) {
      errors.password = "";
      setErrors(errors);
    }
  };

  const handleChangePasswordConfirmation = (event) => {
    setUser({
      ...user,
      passwordConfirmation: event.target.value,
    });
    if (user.passwordConfirmation) {
      errors.passwordConfirmation = "";
      setErrors(errors);
    }
    if (user.passwordConfirmation === user.password) {
      errors.confirm_password = "";
      setErrors(errors);
    }
  };

  const validate = () => {
    const validateErrors = {};
    let isValid = true;
    if (!user.email) {
      isValid = false;
      validateErrors.email = "Please enter a valid email";
    }
    if (!user.password) {
      isValid = false;
      validateErrors.password = "Please enter a valid password";
    } else if (user.password.length < 8) {
      isValid = false;
      validateErrors.password = "Password must be min 8 characters";
    }
    if (!user.passwordConfirmation) {
      isValid = false;
      validateErrors.passwordConfirmation = "Please confirm password";
    } else if (user.passwordConfirmation.length < 8) {
      isValid = false;
      validateErrors.passwordConfirmation = "Password must be min 8 characters";
    }

    if (user.password !== user.passwordConfirmation) {
      isValid = false;
      validateErrors.confirm_password = "Passwords does not match.";
    } else {
      validateErrors.confirm_password = "";
    }

    setErrors(validateErrors);

    return isValid;
  };
  const handleSubmitSignup = (event) => {
    const handleErrors = {};
    event.preventDefault();
    const userData = `email=${user.email}&password=${user.password}&
        passwordConfirmation=${user.passwordConfirmation}`;

    if (validate()) {
      axios
        .post(api, userData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.succes) {
            setIsSubmittedSignup(true);
            setErrorAlert("hide-error");
            setSuccessAlert("show-success");
            setFadeProp({ fade: "fade-in" });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response.data.message) {
            handleErrors.msgSignup = error.response.data.message;
            setErrors(handleErrors);
            setIsSubmittedSignup(false);
            setSuccessAlert("hide-success");
            setErrorAlert("show-error");
            setFadeProp({ fade: "fade-in" });
          }
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col />
        <Col className="loginColumn" lg={4} md={6} sm={6}>
          <Card className="text-center">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title className="p-2">User Registration</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmitSignup}>
                  {isSubmittedSignup ? (
                    <Alert variant="success" className={`${fadeProp.fade} ${successAlert}`}>
                      Successfully Registered.
                    </Alert>
                  ) : (
                    ""
                  )}
                  {errors.msgSignup ? (
                    <Alert variant="danger" className={`${fadeProp.fade} ${errorAlert}`}>
                      {errors.msgSignup}
                    </Alert>
                  ) : (
                    ""
                  )}
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingInput" label="Email address" className="mb-3">
                      <Form.Control type="email" value={user.email} name="email" placeholder="Enter email" onChange={handleChangeEmail} />
                      {errors.email ? <span className="text-danger float-start">{errors.email}</span> : ""}
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingPassword" label="Password">
                      <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={user.password}
                        onChange={handleChangePassword}
                      />
                      {errors.password ? <span className="text-danger float-start">{errors.password}</span> : ""}
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingPassword" label="Confirm password">
                      <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        value={user.passwordConfirmation}
                        name="passwordConfirmation"
                        onChange={handleChangePasswordConfirmation}
                        placeholder="Confirm password"
                      />
                      {errors.passwordConfirmation ? <span className="text-danger float-start">{errors.passwordConfirmation}</span> : ""}
                      {errors.confirm_password ? <span className="text-danger float-start">{errors.confirm_password}</span> : ""}
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                    <Row className="g-2">
                      <Col md>
                        <Link to="/login" className="float-right">
                          Already have an Account?
                        </Link>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <div className="d-grid">
                    <Button type="submit" variant="primary" data-cy="submit-registration">
                      Sign Up
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </Form>
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col />
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default UserRegistration;
```

Comment: `set...` is asynchronous, so reading `user.passwordConfirmation` right after `setUser` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @AKX, Thanks for the comment. Can you please give an example of what I need to do.  how do i make this work?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Writing an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment says, `setState` is asynchronous, so you can't `set...` and then immediately try to read the same state atom. You'll just see the old value.

Instead of validating things in the change handlers, you can derive the errors state based on the other state of the component.

(I removed some of the animation stuff from this example. You can put it back.)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Alert, Button, Card, Col, Container, FloatingLabel, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

const api = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST}/api/register`;

function UserRegistration() {
  // `null` means the user hasn't touched the field yet,
  // so no need to show validation either
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    email: null,
    password: null,
    passwordConfirmation: null,
  });
  const [isSubmittedSignup, setIsSubmittedSignup] = useState(false);
  const [signupError, setSignupError] = useState(null);

  // Universal change handler, looks at the name of the field
  // being changed. Could be `useCallback`ed.
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setUser((user) => ({
      ...user,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  };

  // Derive errors based on `user`.
  const errors = React.useMemo(() => {
    const errors = {};
    if (user.email !== null) {
      if (!user.email) {
        errors.email = "Please enter a valid email";
      }
    }
    if (user.password !== null) {
      if (!user.password) {
        errors.password = "Please enter a valid password";
      } else if (user.password.length < 8) {
        errors.password = "Password must be min 8 characters";
      }
    }
    if (user.passwordConfirmation !== null) {
      if (!user.passwordConfirmation) {
        errors.passwordConfirmation = "Please confirm password";
      } else if (user.passwordConfirmation.length < 8) {
        errors.passwordConfirmation = "Password must be min 8 characters";
      } else if (user.password !== user.passwordConfirmation) {
        errors.passwordConfirmation = "Passwords does not match.";
      }
    }
    return errors;
  }, [user]);

  // If there are no `errors`, the form is valid.
  // Could also be `useMemo`'d, but no real need to.
  const isValid = Object.keys(errors).length === 0;

  const handleSubmitSignup = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!isValid) {
      alert("Please correct errors first.");
      return;
    }
    const userData = `email=${user.email}&password=${user.password}&passwordConfirmation=${user.passwordConfirmation}`;

    setIsSubmittedSignup(false);
    try {
      let res = await axios.post(api, userData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      });
      if (res.data.success) {
        setIsSubmittedSignup(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.data.message) {
        setSignupError(error.response.data.message);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col />
        <Col className="loginColumn" lg={4} md={6} sm={6}>
          <Card className="text-center">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title className="p-2">User Registration</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmitSignup}>
                  {isSubmittedSignup ? <Alert variant="success">Successfully Registered.</Alert> : null}
                  {signupError ? <Alert variant="danger">{signupError}</Alert> : null}
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingInput" label="Email address" className="mb-3">
                      <Form.Control type="email" value={user.email} name="email" placeholder="Enter email" onChange={handleChange} />
                      {errors.email ? <span className="text-danger float-start">{errors.email}</span> : null}
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingPassword" label="Password">
                      <Form.Control type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={user.password} onChange={handleChange} />
                      {errors.password ? <span className="text-danger float-start">{errors.password}</span> : null}
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingPassword" label="Confirm password">
                      <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        value={user.passwordConfirmation}
                        name="passwordConfirmation"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        placeholder="Confirm password"
                      />
                      {errors.passwordConfirmation ? <span className="text-danger float-start">{errors.passwordConfirmation}</span> : null}
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                    <Row className="g-2">
                      <Col md>
                        <a href="/login" className="float-right">
                          Already have an Account?
                        </a>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <div className="d-grid">
                    <Button type="submit" variant="primary" data-cy="submit-registration">
                      Sign Up
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </Form>
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default UserRegistration;
```